# Select attribute not changed after change of select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a table in which a few columns contains select elements. In the tfoot I have one input element for each row used for filtering the row based on the selected value in the select element.

When loading the table and directly filtering the columns with selects, than it works and the table is filtered.

But when making a change in the select elements, the filter function is not taking any notice that the value has changed.

Checking out the html I can see that the "selected" attribute is still on the option that was selected when loading. Hence, it doesn't get updated when making an actual changed (identified in both FF and Chrome).

But from jQuery, searching for the selected value (`.find(":selected")`) works. So I figure that I can use that to find the value and then set the selected attribute to whatever was selected. This is how I am trying to do it:

```
$("select[id^='qu_owner']").live('change', function (e) {
    var owner = $(this).val();
    console.log(owner);
    var ticketid = $(this).attr('id').substr(9);
    $($(this) + " option[value=" + owner + "]").attr("selected", "selected"); //Update: this has been removed
});
```

But the selected attribute is still not updated in the element.

Any clue how to do this? I need the filtering to work and it's looking at the selected attibute. Is it not possible to make this kind of update to the select element?

---

**UPDATE**

Ok, based on the comments and answers below I understand there are better ways of doing what I did above. So instead of using $(this).find(":selected").val(); I now use $(this).val();. Also, I did remove the last row since I understand one shouldn't try to set the selected attribute.

And also, I now understand that the code where I have the actual problem is the filter function. This is for DataTables so it's a plugin but this is the significant part:

aData[i] is the actual table cell. Hence, it's just text but in this case it's the text for my select element. I think below is heading in the right direction, but still not working (check comments next to console.log-rows):

```
function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {

                var ret = true;    

                    //Loop through all input fields i tfoot that has class 'sl_filter' attached                                              
                   $('tfoot .sl_filter').each(function(i, obj){

                       //$(this) can be used. Get the index of this colum.
                       var i = $("tfoot input").index($(this));                           

                       //Create regexp to math
                       var r = new RegExp($(this).val(), "i");

                       //Get the selected option from the column
                        console.log($(aData[i]).attr('id')); //Properly prints the ID
                        console.log($(aData[i] + " option:selected").text()); //Prints all options, not only the selected on
                        console.log($(aData[i] + " option:selected").val()); //Prints the value of the id that was selected when data was loaded, even if a new option has been chosen
                        console.log($(aData[i]).val()); //Prints the value of the id that was selected when data was loaded, even if a new option has been chosen

                        var str = $(aData[i] + " option:selected").text();                          

                       /*Test to see if there is a match or if the input value is the default 
                         (the initial value of input before it has any fokus/text) */                           
                       if(r.test(str) || $(this).val()=="Search"){
                           //Return true only exits this function
                           return true;
                       }else{

                           /*Return false returns both function an .each. Retain 'false' in a variable scoped
                             to be reached outside the .each */                                
                           ret = false;
                           return false;
                       }
                   });
                   //Return true or false
                    return ret;                        
                }
```

It is the text for the selected element I need to get hold of. That's what should be filtered upon. How can I do that?

---

**Update**

To narrow it down, I have created a jsfiddle with what's necessary. It's all about how to extract the text from the selected option: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLghD/1/)

aData[i] = the table cell. In jsfiddle, i use "sel" as variable for the content of the cell. The text for sel is copied form aData[i].

Comment: So your listening for `change` on a select to then select the currently selected option ?!?!

Comment: @ManseUK apparently he's trying to fool some other jQuery function into thinking that the _attribute_ has changed, rather than the _property_.

Comment: @Alnitak sounds sane .... perhaps fixing the problem might be a good idea ....

Comment: @Nicsoft please show whatever code it is you have that _isn't_ working - "_the filter function is not taking any notice that the value has changed_"

Comment: So what does `$("[object Object] option[value=1234]");` select???

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have updated my post based on your reflections. Indeed, the bad part is probably the filter function (even though the part I presented could be improved as well...)

Comment: there's both too much, and too little information here.  I can't tell what `aData` is supposed to be, nor how it relates to your select boxes.  Could you please create a sample on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Good idea. I have created a jsfiddle with necessary information. Check my update.

Comment: ah, right - you just want `$(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).text()`

Comment: @Nicsoft see http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/zLghD/2/ and my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, but I think you changed the problem. I need to get it working as I presented it in my jsfiddle, that javascript function is equivalent with the filter function and how I get the data into that function. I cannot use 'this' in the filter function, it's already used as a table row. As mentioned in a few places here, the problem is not in the change handler, it's in the filter function. I have problems seeing how this can be done since the elment looks the same as when it was first loaded (since the selected attribute isn't moved). It's not the object that is being passed, but the html.

Comment: Hmmm...I guess I have to recreate the object, upon change, and add it to the table cell (and discard existing select element). I don't see any other way now unless anyone out there has got any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to change the *attribute* of the `<option>` - that's supposed to contain the original state of the element as it was downloaded from the server.

Your filter should be checking the `selected` *property* of the chosen option, e.g.:

```
.filter(function() {
    return this.selected; // check the boolean property
})
```

This is also how the `:selected` pseudo-selector works - it checks the current value of the *property*, not the *attribute*.

Note that in the `change` handler for a `<select>` element, you can just use `this.value` to get the currently selected value.

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    // current value
    var value = this.value;   

    // text of the currently selected option.
    var text = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

Comment: @gdoron yes, I know, but he hasn't actually shown the code that doesn't work yet.  All he's shown is a bodged work around.

Comment: All the things I corrected in his code aren't the not working code?

Comment: @gdoron no, that code (even though it doesn't work) is only there to work around some other bug in some code he hasn't shown us yet.

Comment: Thanks, I did change to this.value now.